# Whose reputation?? (on privileges page)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, privileges, moderator-tools

The page https://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges/user/-1 says "Your reputation" rather than "Community's reputation".

Comment: As well as any other user's privileges page that you happen to go to.

Comment: @HodofHod, yes, I should have specified that that was just an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, this feature (being able to see the privileges for other users) was originally intended as a way for moderators / devs to double-check that a particular user was seeing what he was supposed to see. It's not *currently* inaccessible to non-moderators, because there's nothing really *private* there - but it's not particularly useful or easy to find either.

Normally, folks would just view https://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges/ and see their own reputation and earned privileges.

While I agree that the wording is misleading, I'm not sure this should be changed - note that *as a moderator* you'll see this sort of thing in a lot of places: visiting a user's profile invites you to view "my" (their) logins, the wording on the preferences screen implies that you're changing them for yourself, etc.

It's probably just worth keeping in mind that, as a moderator, in order that you may better support users who encounter problems, you get to see things that are normally private and / or presented in the context of a single user viewing his own information.